# Do any action traits indicate that free hands are required?

Tags: pathfinder-2e

What action traits or tags, especially for spells, require the user to have a free hand (if any)?

I am asking because I was caught by surprise to [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/165887/23223) to a question regarding lay on hands and how many free hands it required. Specifically that the somatic trait - which as I understand it means physical movement, such as hand gestures - does not in fact require a free hand.

N.b. I am the GM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When spellcasting, spells with the [material](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=282) component trait explicitly require a free hand to manipulate the physical component. This is true even if the material component itself is unnecessary due to the [Eschew Materials](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=634) feat.

Other actions which require a free hand include:

- [making a Strike with a 1+ hands weapon](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=230)
- using the [Dual-Handed Assault](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=371), [Combat Grab](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=366), [Snagging Strike](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=361), [Dueling Dance](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=407), [Aldori Parry](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=877), [Deflect Arrows](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=443), [Disarming Stance](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=380), [Disarming Twist](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=400), [Dueling Parry](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=367), [Furious Grab](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=163), [Guardian's Deflection](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=382), [Guiding Finish](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=416) and [Sabotage](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=565) feats
- [Activating a non-wielded item with the interact activation component](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=100)
- [Grabbing an edge while falling](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=95) with a non-critical success
- [Starting or continuing a grapple](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=35)
- [Disarming an opponent](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=41) without a [weapon with the disarm trait](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=175)
- [Shoving an opponent](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=38) without a [weapon with the shove trait](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=193)
- [Tripping an opponent](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=40) without a [weapon with the trip trait](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=196)
- Making an item with [Quick Alchemy](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=2)